# List of the most popular answers

Tags: support, feature-request

Recently I've hit  the ~1.0m (people reached) milestone. This is based on the number of views of posts I provided (so far 409 answers and 3 questions). That is roughly 2500 views per post, quite a good statistics.  For example on the Activity part of my profile I can see a list of my questions sorted by the number of views however there is no similar listing for my answers.

I would like to get a **list** (say of length 20) **of the most viewed posts**  of mine as well as for any user of Mathematica.stackexchange (especially for those who gave at least 100 answers/questions).

Can I get such a statistics automatically somwhere on Stackexchange or do I need harnessing something like *SQL*?

For example of  nice exploiting of *SQL* see a diligent answer by [C. E.](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) to my old query [Toward Mathematica.Stackexchange analytics](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/toward-mathematica-stackexchange-analytics).

Comment: Try this: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/752654/?UserID=184

Comment: @SimonWoods  Thanks, I guess this is an acceptable answer to my question, unless someone provides in two weeks e.g. a _Mathematica_ based approach solving such a task.

Comment: @SimonWoods This provides statistics for the question views actually, so if an answer is posted after several years of the question, it will have the same number of views as the question according to this statistics...

Comment: @SimonWoods Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) website to get all sorts of statistics like this.

Here is a simple query that returns the top 20 most viewed questions which you have posted an answer to: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/752654/

(Enter your user ID in the box and click on Run Query.)

As pointed out by Alexey Popkov in a comment, this is not the same as the number of views of your answers. I don't know if it's possible to get that data.

**Update**

Here's a modified version that adds an "EstimatedViews" column which is simply the question view count scaled by the age of the answer relative to the age of the question. So answers posted later will have a lower EstimatedViews count.

https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/754773